# Membership Provider and asp:Login not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I may be doing this all wrong, but after several hours googling and searching I once again has to ask the fine folks here at StackOverflow. I'm trying to add a Login controller to my aspx WebForms site.  I have done the following :

- Added the appropriate values to WebConfig.
- Set up my database with the aspnet_regsql (Using the v4.0 framework / Site is running 4.5 (Is this a issue?)
- Added a createUserWizard and checked if users get added to the database. (Working)
- Checked if application ID / Name is the same as the users gets assigned in the database.

I first tried to have the login form in my default.aspx site using `<asp:LoginView>` combined with `<LoggedInTemplate>` & `<AnonymousTemplate>`. If I supply the form with credentials that match a user registered with the CreateUserWizard, I get no error, and it redirects me. But I'm still not logged in. If I supply false credentials it gives me a "Wrong username / password error" so it has to be able to connect and validate the credentials.

I'm a bit lost at this point, because no errors are presented, and I'm unsure how I should continue the error-search. I also tried adding a second site called "login.aspx" with the same results.

**My webconfig**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="userconn" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-NVAAFR9N703\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SomeUser;Password=ValidPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
  </connectionStrings>

<system.web>
  <machineKey validationKey="MANYNUMBERS" decryptionKey="EVEN_MORE_NUMBERS" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />  
  <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
           connectionStringName="userconn"
           passwordFormat="Encrypted"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
           enablePasswordReset="false"
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
           requiresUniqueEmail="true"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
           minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
           passwordAttemptWindow="30"
           applicationName="/BlackJack"
           />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Login Form**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProperLogin.ascx.cs" Inherits="BlacjJack.ProperLogin" %>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400" rel="stylesheet" />

<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" MembershipProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" DestinationPageUrl="~/default.aspx" VisibleWhenLoggedIn="False">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <div class="row half">
                <div class="12u">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="text" Text="Username"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="12u">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="12u">
                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                </div>

                <div class="12u">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />

                </div>
                <div class="12u">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1" CssClass="button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

**CreateUserWizard**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProperRegister.ascx.cs" Inherits="BlacjJack.ProperRegister" %>

<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" MembershipProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" Style="margin-right: 0px">
    <ContinueButtonStyle CssClass="button" />
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

What I tried after getting some tips from you guys :

- Added a label, in the `AnonymouseTemplate`, it runs a test on `User.Identity.isAuthenticated`, and it returns false. Even tough no error occours.
- I installed fiddler check the screenshot below, it gets a cookie when i submit the login form.

[image: Fiddler HTTP data inspect.]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the login control isn't responsible for keeping session state. You need to set a session variable that the user is logged in, or some other way of persisting that a user is logged in, which is then checked on every page load to keep state.

Comment: I thought it handled this automatically with the .ASPXAUTH session coockie / FormsAuthentication?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You're right. Not sure on this one.

Comment: "But I'm still not logged in" - Why do you think you aren't logged in? Perhaps because your LoginView is displaying the AnonymousTemplate.  But there may be other reasons for this (e.g. output caching). I would start by double checking this - run under the debugger and check User.Identity.Name and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated after logging in to see if you're really logged in.  Use Fiddler to examine the HTTP traffic and check for the presence of the Forms Authentication cookie.

Comment: I'l check. Tough I added a LoginStatus and LoginName controller in the  AnonymousTemplate, and that just showed me a "Log in" buton. Even tough I should be "logged in".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it. It seems like I was missing an Authentication method in my WebConfig. 
I added :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Login1" loginUrl="~/default.aspx" path="/"
    cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

And everything seems to work alright now.

**Web.Config now looks like this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="userconn" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-NVAAFR9N703\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usr;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Login1" loginUrl="~/default.aspx" path="/"
        cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>

  <machineKey validationKey="NUMBERS" decryptionKey="NUMHBERS" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

  <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider3">
    <providers>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider3"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
           connectionStringName="userconn"
           passwordFormat="Encrypted"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
           enablePasswordReset="false"
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
           requiresUniqueEmail="true"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
           minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
           passwordAttemptWindow="30"
           applicationName="/BlackJack"
           />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```